# Workflow used to email user when an opportunity has a close date in the past not working

Tags: email, workflow, alert

I have a workflow rule set to auto email a user when they have an opportunity with a close date in the past. The issue I am having is that some users (not all) are getting these email alerts even when the opportunity has already been closed won. The evaluation criteria is set to "evaluate the rule when a record is created, and any time it's edited t subsequently meet criteria". No changes made to the record after closed won so I can't see what the issue is. Can anyone advise? thanks

Comment: welcome to SFSE. Please see [ask] for getting the most from the Community.  I would suggest you use [edit] to show your WFR (screenshot)

Answer (score 0):

Add an exclusion to the workflow rule to not run for "Closed Won" opportunities.

e.g.

```
closeDate < TODAY()
&& stageName != "Closed Won"
```

or (however you have your rule currently):

```
AND (
    closeDate < TODAY(),
    stageName != "Closed Won"
)
```

or if it's in criteria form:

```
Close Date - not equal - TODAY
Stage - not equal - Closed Won
```